# How to make animation curve more smooth

Tags: animation

[image]

I am making a keyframe animation in Blender. I have some problems with this curve.

1. The curve between keyframes is so weird. I try to use "T" to change a different curve style. But it doesn't work.
2. So I try to modify these curves one by one. I move the handles. But I can't click the handle dot to rotate the handle. If I click the handle it shows moving the keyframe.[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can smooth your keys by selecting all points you want to smooth and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Press again and again until it is smooth enough.

Example:

Before:

[image]

One time <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>:

[image]

several times:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Probably you have proportional editing activated, which seems to move the whole keyframe instead of single anchor point.

Then T changes the interpolation mode (linear, bezier, bounce, ...) while you'd want to use V instead, which lets you choose the kind of keyframe handle (free, aligned, automatic, ....).

[image]

Comment: Thank you again!!!!!!

Comment: @garyyang Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).